# sorted() function on python for tuple

Tags: python, function, sorting, tuples

in this code , a tuple must be sorted but i ask a question of user that what kind of sort want, but the question asked four times:

```
students = (("st_1", "a", "40"),
            ("st_2", "b", "38"),
            ("st_3", "c", "32"),
            ("st_4", "a", "10"))
def key_sort(keys):
    index = 0
    what_sort = input("do you sort a list ? n for name , g for grade and a for age : ").lower()
    if what_sort == 'a':
        index = keys[2]
    elif what_sort == 'n':
        index = keys[0]
    elif what_sort == 'g':
        index = keys[1]
return index        

sorted_students = sorted(students, key=key_sort)
for i in sorted_students:    
    print(i)
```

why ask question four times?
[terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZrY.png)

Comment: because key_sort gets called for every item in the list ...

Comment: Take the input beforehand and call the function and then pass the value to sorted

Answer (score 2):

Ask first, then construct an appropriate function to pass to `sorted`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

what_sort = input("do you sort a list ? n for name , g for grade and a for age : ").lower()

if what_sort == 'a':
    n = 2
elif what_sort == 'n':
    n = 0
elif what_sort == 'g':
    n = 1
else:
    n = 0  # Pick a good default      


sorted_students = sorted(students, key=itemgetter(n))
```

Comment: or `n = {"a": 2, "n": 0, "g": 1}.get(what_sort, 0)`, +1 still

Comment: A small cost, but I like to avoid the cost of building a `dict` only to index it once. Of course, here I'm making repeated comparisons to `what_sort` rather than a single hash operation. I have no idea where the break-even point X would be (fewer than X choices, use an `if-elif` chain; more than X, index a `dict`)

Comment: I think this will just confuse OP. If they don't understand how to use `key`, what makes you think they'll understand `itemgetter`? At the very least you should explain how the function works.

Comment: They don't need to understand `itemgetter` (which isn't that hard to understand in the first place: `itemgetter(n) ==  lambda x: x[n]`).

Answer (score 0):

`key=key_sort` means that for each item `key`, the `sorted()` function will call `key_sort(key)` to determine the sorting order of that key. You have an `input()` in that function, and if there are 4 items in the list, that means `key_sort()` will have been called 4 times. It's just Python working as designed. If you want the input to not run every time, you have to use some kind of condition. Or, what would make more sense is to ask for the sorting method beforehand, and then set a class or global variable `what_sort` that `key_sort` then uses.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541038/joran-beasley) pointed out, the `key` argument in `sorted` is called to every element in the iterable to be sorted (in your case, the variable `students`).

A way to obtain the behavior you are asking is to modify the `key_sort` function to return **another function** which should be used as the `key` argument in your `sorted` call.

Please consider the following code

```
students = (("st_1", "a", "40"),
            ("st_2", "b", "38"),
            ("st_3", "c", "32"),
            ("st_4", "a", "10"))

def key_sort():
    index = 0
    what_sort = input("do you sort a list ? n for name , g for grade and a for age : ").lower()
    if what_sort == 'a':
        index = 2
    elif what_sort == 'n':
        index = 0
    elif what_sort == 'g':
        index = 1
    return lambda student: student[index]

key_fn = key_sort()
sorted_students = sorted(students, key=key_fn)
for i in sorted_students:    
    print(i)
```

That way, the user interaction (the `input` function call) will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter in the `sorted` function is the name of a function used to get the value to sort on. For example, in a list of integers, this is unnecessary because of course the objects themselves can directly be compared and sorted. But for tuples, it isn't clear how they should be compared. Using the first element? The last one? A hash of all of them? Python can't answer that question. `key` exists so you can specify how to do it.

The solution to your particular problem is to first ask the user the question, and then use their answer to choose how to sort the list. There's a lot of ways to do this, but here's how I think is the simplest.

```
students = (("st_1", "a", "40"),
            ("st_2", "b", "38"),
            ("st_3", "c", "32"),
            ("st_4", "a", "10"))

def get_name(student):
    return student[0]

def get_grade(student):
    return student[1]

def get_age(student):
    return student[2]

sort_index = input("How should the list be sorted? (n for name , g for grade and a for age) : ").lower()

if sort_index == 'n':
    sorted_students = sorted(students, key=get_name)
elif sort_index == 'g':
    sorted_students = sorted(students, key=get_grade)
elif sort_index == 'a':
    sorted_students = sorted(students, key=get_age)
else:
    print('Unsupported option')
    exit(1)

print(sorted_students)
```